# The image not loading inside ImageView

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

I am trying to retrieve image from the firebase, However, the image is not loading inside the Imageview instead, it loads inside textView somehow and shows firebase storage image address, however, the textview not even attached with Image

```
public class AdapterSearch extends RecyclerView.Adapter <AdapterSearch.SearchViewHolder>{
                Context context;
                ArrayList<String>titlelist;
                ArrayList<String>locationlist;
                ArrayList<String>imagelist;
                ArrayList<String>pricelist;

         class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image;
        TextView  title,location,price;

        public SearchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
              super(itemView);

        price=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_event_price);
        image=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_event_img);
        title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id._search_event_title);
        location=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_event_location);


                    }
                }


         public AdapterSearch(Context context, ArrayList<String> mtitlelist, ArrayList<String> mlocationlist,ArrayList<String> mimagelist, ArrayList<String> mpricelist) {

                this.context = context;
                this.titlelist = mtitlelist;
                this.locationlist = mlocationlist;
                this.imagelist = mimagelist;
                this.pricelist= mpricelist;
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public AdapterSearch.SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

                    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_list,viewGroup,false);

                return new AdapterSearch.SearchViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder searchViewHolder, int i) {

                    searchViewHolder.price.setText(pricelist.get(i));
                    searchViewHolder.title.setText(titlelist.get(i));
                    searchViewHolder.location.setText(locationlist.get(i));

                    Glide.with(context).asBitmap().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).load(imagelist.get(i)).into(searchViewHolder.image);
        searchViewHolder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: imageList is the url of the photo inside your storage ?

Comment: yes, its url from Firebase storage

Comment: The current code its an adapter

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if your image is not loaded check error in onException and try to resolve your Error okay

```
Glide.with(contect)
    .load(imagelist.get(i))
    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> 
        target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, 
Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
       return false;
        }
    }).into(searchViewHolder.image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats exactly is in `imageList.get(i)`? Is that firebase storage URI or download URL?

Might it be that the raw Glide cannot process the storage path?
You can try to use FirebaseUI to load images with Glide, using only Firebase Storage paths without getting download urls: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?authuser=0#downloading_images_with_firebaseui

But it requires setup first: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/README.md

Comment: ImageList its downloaded URL and its just loading URL  somehow to search_event_title to the textview :(

Comment: Glide itself wouldn't do it. Check the strings you set for textviews in `onBindViewHolder` with a `Log.d()` or with a debugger to see whats actually happening. And it is possible that you misjudge whats loading in what element because the layout elements can jump to other positions and change bounds when the image is loaded

Comment: the error:  Glide: Load failed for 18+ with size [354x287]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource